# Iterate over types of tuple in C++

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, std, template-meta-programming

I want to iterate over types of a tuple, not its elements.
Imagine you have a generic, base-class interface `Controller` and you want to have a vector of pointers (*I use raw pointer instead of smart, for readability*): `std::vector<Controller*> ctrls;`

Now you want to add many implementations of `Controller` interface to this vector, so you can do this:

```
ctrls.emplace_back(new MouseCtrl());
ctrls.emplace_back(new KeyboardCtrl());
ctrls.emplace_back(new ScreenCtrl());
(... and so on)
```

But this is ugly and not exactly extendable (as in Open-Close Principle), so it would be better to have, for example, a tuple: `using Controllers = std::tuple<MouseCtrl, KeyboardCtrl, ScreenCtrl>;` and then, in the some init function, iterate over those types:

```
for (T : Controllers> { 
   ctrls.emplace_back(new T());
}
```

Obviously, the code above it's not valid C++ syntax. **So the question is: how to do this?**. I've looked both into std::apply and std::visit / std::variant, but I don't have idea how to do this (they iterate over elements, not types).

Comment: Types in a tuple can be iterated only at compile time.

Comment: `std::tuple` is a value type. If you just want to default construct your elements you can just default construct the `std::tuple`. If you need more sophisticated initialization the question arises how that should be done in your case which i am afraid we can'T answere without further information. In general you "iterate" over types with *variadic templates*

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't really answer the question if you cannot construct the tuple. Here's a solution that works purely with the types: https://godbolt.org/z/rYfGoj (which I can't answer on a closed question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple_size` and `std::tuple_element` to get the type of every tuple element (this will put it in reverse order, but with a little modification you can revert the order):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

using Controllers = tuple<int, char, float>;
using ControllersContainer = vector<variant<int, char, float>>;

template <size_t N>
void add(ControllersContainer& ctrls)
{
    ctrls.emplace_back(tuple_element_t<N-1, Controllers>{});
    add<N - 1>(ctrls);
}

template <>
void add<0>(ControllersContainer& ctrls)
{
    ctrls.emplace_back(tuple_element_t<0, Controllers>{});
}

int main()
{
    ControllersContainer ctrls;
    add<tuple_size_v<Controllers>>(ctrls);
}
```

Comment: Important to note that this will only work at compile-time. Probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: The question was about iterating over a types in a tuple. A tuple is a static type - "iteration" is possible only at compile time. Although iteration here is implemented with recursion.

Comment: @StPiere This is exactly was I was looking for. Do you know if there is anything in the standard lib that already provide this kind of functionality - so that I could skip adding "add" function and just provide some Lambda fun with `ctrls.emplace_back(tuple_element_t<0, Controllers>{});` ?

Comment: @zupazit: I'm not aware of direct method. One other possibility would be to go over make_index_sequence and tuple_size with comma operator.

Answer (score 0):

If C++20 is allowed, there is a more convenient way to solve this:

```
template<typename T, typename FUNC>
static inline constexpr void for_each_type(FUNC&& func)
{
    auto  __hander = []<typename T, typename FUNC, size_t... I>(FUNC && func, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
        (func.template operator() < std::tuple_element_t<I, T> > (), ...);
    };
    __hander.template operator() < T > (
        std::forward<FUNC>(func),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<T>::value>{}
    );
}
```

Now you have two classes with same method, and make they a tuple:

```
class A
{
public:
    static const char* name() { return "A"; };
};

class B
{
public:
    static const char* name() { return "B"; };
};
using AB = std::tuple<A, B>;
```

And then:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for_each_type<AB>(
        []<typename T>()
        {
            std::cout << T::name() << std::endl;
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```